# add click event to ngx-datatable cell body

Tags: javascript, angular6, ngx-datatable

I want to call a function in click event of ngx-datatable cell body. This is the code I have right now.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="User Name" prop="userName">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
       <span *ngIf="!editable" (click)="editable = true;"> Some Text </span>
       <input type="text" *ngIf="editable"/>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

I want to move the stuff in span click event into cell body click event. I got few problems when I trying to move,

1. ng-template (click) event not working,
2. then I tried to add a div inside the ng-template but it only cover the span area. Witch means the div not covering whole cell body. (Am not allowed to change the default styles of the cell)

Answer (score 0):

**Can you Please try with this**

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="User Name" prop="userName">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
       <span *ngIf="!editable" (dblclick)="editable = true;"> Some Text </span>
       <input type="text" autofocus *ngIf="editable"/>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: The click event is still in the span right..? :) .. Thanks for the help @aneri-vala . But that's not what I want.